# I'm trying to make a live chat with django and orbited but I keep getting errors

Tags: javascript, python, django, stomp, orbited

I'm following [this tutorial](http://mischneider.net/?p=125) on how to setup a simple django/orbited/stomp live chat, and I've followed everything exactly how he does it, and I've even copied all of his code, but I still get this one weird error that I don't understand.

When I go to the website, I get an alert that just says "Error". When I look at what Firebug has to say, it tells me these two errors:

```
Illegal document.domain value"  code: "1009
http://127.0.0.1:9000/static/xsdrBridge.html
Line 68

Permission denied to access property 'Orbited'
http://127.0.0.1:9000/static/xsdrBridge.html
Line 92
```

I followed the tutorial exactly to the dot but I cannot figure out why I'm getting these errors. I run orbited by:

```
orbited -c orbited.cnf
```

and I run my django development server by:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds like cross domain problems for the JS?  You are running the dev server on 0.0.0.0 and orbited on 127.0.0.1.  Could be it.  How are you accessing the page with your web browser?

Try running orbited and the django dev server on 0.0.0.0 and also using this ip to visit the page in your browser.

Comment: If I don't run the django dev server on 0.0.0.0 then I'm not able to access it from any computer other than the one it's hosted on, so the guys in the django IRC told me to use 0.0.0.0 instead and that got it working. However, I tried running it on 127.0.0.1 and I still get the same error. I'm going there with my web browser by going to http://localhost:8000/comet/